# Angular OAuth2 Check for Privileges in Guard

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular-router-guards

In my app, I need to only allow users with certain privileges to view certain "pages".  I thought the best way to do this was to create a PrivilegeGuard.  I currently have an AuthGuard (I'm utilizing https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc) that runs first and if the user does not have a valid auth token, it returns `this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin()`.  I need to parse claims from the token and check them in the PrivilegeGuard.  The issue I am having is that the claims are always null in the PrivilegeGuard (because they haven't been parsed yet).  I was subscribed to oauth events in app.component.ts and parsing claims on success, but the guards are firing before this occurs.

It felt like a hack, but I tried parsing in the AuthGuard, but even after the user logs in, `this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()` is not yet true as it still has to load the discovery document.

I tried converting the promise to an observable and parsing in a pipe/map, but that seems to never be called.

```
return from(this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin()).pipe(
      map((result) => {
        console.log('This is not called.');

        return result;
      })
    );
```

Even if it was called, looking at the console, the discovery call completes after the PrivilegeGuard code runs.

Is there a way for the PrivilegeGuard to wait for the discovery call to complete so that I can parse the claims?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up utilizing a `ReplaySubject` that had a flag set when the claims were parsed.  I then subscribed to it in the PrivilegeGuard.  `BehaviorSubject` did not work as it had a default value would the PrivilegeGuard would immediately just take that value.  `Subject` didn't work as it only sent out the flag once that `canActivate` heard, but `canActivateChild` just sat waiting.  With `ReplaySubject`, `canActivateChild` was able to just grab the last emitted value.